Overture Maps data for searching places and geocoding
I've been reading about the new Overture Maps Foundation led by Amazon, Meta and Microsoft.  The 'Places' dataset has over 50 million locations and looks to be the most complete open source dataset.
Does anyone have any experience hosting this data themselves?  Or is there an online service or provider that already hosts this dataset in an easily-searched API?

You have reached the correct place. Dataset is hosted at Amazon and Azure and data can be queried from there. Start reading at https://docs.overturemaps.org/getting-data/#getting-a-small-to-medium-amount-of-data-recommended.

ThinkGeo Cloud uses a combination of Overture Maps and OpenStreetMap data for its geocoding endpoints.   You can learn more here.
Make sure to set the IncludeOverturePlaces flag to true when calling the geocode endpoint.
